# (Laravel)Troubles while connecting to docker database SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I've built a laravel app using docker with two containers, `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    users:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            DB_HOST: db
            DB_USERNAME: root
            DB_DATABASE: users
            DB_PASSWORD: root
        command: 'php artisan serve'
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - 8001:8000
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: users
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
            - ./storage/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 33069:3306
```

my `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=33069
DB_DATABASE=users
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

But when I try to run `php artisan migrate`, it results in

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = users and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

      +36 vendor frames
  37  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I run the migrations inside the users container, also I ran `php artisan config:clear` and tried to create a custom user with root privileges, the error is the same.
When I try to connect to database via the phpStorm it succeeds.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are you running `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: inside the docker container, I mean after `docker-compose exec users sh`

Comment: and you are able to connect using `mysql -u root -p` in `docker-compose exec db sh`?

Comment: yes, it succeeds 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.22 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Comment: Does this `select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = users and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'` command work?

Comment: That's an Epmty set

Comment: You're connecting to port 33069, but the MySQL server is listening on port 3306.  Connections between containers always use the "normal" ports, they don't require `ports:` and they ignore them if present.